# Is it possible to increment iterator in loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator, increment

I would like to increment iterator i in loop in Python. The code below:

```
for i in range(0,10):   
    print(i, end="")
    if i % 3 == 0:
        i += 2
    else if i % 3 == 0:
        i += 3
```

In such way the output of this code is:

```
0123456789
```

But should be different. Thanks.

Comment: `for i in range(0,10,2): print i`

Comment: What you mean by *different* whats your expected output?

Comment: If you want to alter the step on the fly, you could use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is reassigned at every iteration; that's how the `for` loop works. If you want to skip every second number (i.e. iterate in steps of 2), you'll need to do this:

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i, end="")
```

That third parameter of the `range` function, called `step`, just determines what `i` is incremented by in each iteration.

Comment: `i` can not be reassigned due to variable scope, use a `while` loop and a sentry variable.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Right, but a `for` loop with the `range` function is more suitable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `step` argument in `range` function :

```
>>> for i in range(0,10,2):   
...     print(i, end="")
... 
>>> 02468
```

Note that after each iteration the for loop change the value of `i` so you shouldn't change it after `print`!

If you do it before printing you'll get the following result :

```
>>> for i in range(0,10,2):
...     i += 2
...     print(i, end="")
... 
>>> 246810
```